# porting an app to iPad: alternatives for a context-menu? UI advice please

Tags: ipad, focus, contextmenu

Considering porting/rewriting an app for the iPad and need some UI advice. On the iPad is there a way to pop a context-menu up from a text field without the text field losing focus?  If not, what is the closest thing in the UI to this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In 3.2, the [`menuItems` of the UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008301-CH1-SW17) can be customized, so you could just add your items into that array.

If you don't need the text field to be interactive than the menu appears, you could also use a pop-over or action sheet for more flexibility. Make that text field `-becomeFirstResponder` after that context menu is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The functionality needed is character-insertion and selection-replace.  The selectionStart and selectionEnd indices of the text-field cannot be lost when the context-menu is opened. The context-menu choice returns a string which either gets inserted into the field at the insertion point, or it replaces any selected text.